# MVC 4 ASPX to Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

New to Razor, trying to convert the following:

```
                <select id="Province" name="Province" style="width: 235px; background-color: #FFFFCC;">
                    <%
       string[] provinces = ViewBag.ProvincesForSelectedCountry;
       string selectedProvinceName;
       if (Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Province))
           selectedProvinceName = Model.Province;
       else
           selectedProvinceName = ConfigData.DefaultProvinceName;

       foreach (var anEntry in provinces)
       {
           string selectedTextMark = anEntry == selectedProvinceName ? " selected=\"selected\"" : String.Empty;
                    %>
                    <option value="<%= anEntry %>" <%= selectedTextMark %>>
                        <%= anEntry %></option>
                    <%
       }
                    %>
                </select>
            </td>
```

The Razor:

```
            <select id="Province" name="Province" style="width: 235px; background-color: #FFFFCC;">
                @string[] provinces = ViewBag.ProvincesForSelectedCountry;
   string selectedProvinceName;
   if (Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Province))
       selectedProvinceName = Model.Province;
   else
       selectedProvinceName = ConfigData.DefaultProvinceName;

   foreach (var anEntry in provinces)
   {
       string selectedTextMark = anEntry == selectedProvinceName ? " selected=\"selected\"" : String.Empty;

                <option value="@anEntry" @selectedTextMark>
                    @anEntry</option>

   }

            </select>
        </td>
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid expression term 'string' in  @string[] provinces = viewBag.ProvincesForSelectedCountry;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
@{
    string[] provinces = ViewBag.ProvincesForSelectedCountry;
```

and then a closing `}` before the `</select>` tag.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, now I found another error:   @Dictionary<string, string> countryCodeNamePairs = ViewBag.CountryCodeNameDictionary;  string is invalid expression!!

Comment: Any idea how to convert: <%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="WebControlCaptcha" Assembly="WebControlCaptcha" %>  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no, but Intellisense should help.  Try typing `@Reg` and see what comes up.  Failing that the docs at asp.net should help.